# DataTemplate inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Im new on wpf, and ive been having this problem...

I want to show a "Complex" object in my view
the complex object named WeeklySchedule:

that have a list of "Shifts"

```
public class WeeklySchedule
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
    .....
}


public class Shift
{
    public virtual String EntryTime { get; set; }
    public virtual String ExitTime { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Im using two Data Templates to try and show the content in these objects:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ShiftlistViewTemplate" DataType="viewModel:WorkScheduleViewModel">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding EntryTime}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ExitTime}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="WeeklySchedulelistViewTemplate"
                      DataType="viewModel:WorkScheduleViewModel">
                    <ListView x:Name="ShiftListView" 
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShiftlistViewTemplate}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Shifts}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShift, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
```

In the viewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
     public Shift SelectedShift
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedShift;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedShift == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedShift = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedShiftPropertyName);
        }
    }
     public ObservableCollection<WorkSchedule> WorkSchedules
     {
        get
        {
            return _workSchedules;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_workSchedules == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _workSchedules = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(WorkSchedulePropertyName);
        }
     }

    public ObservableCollection<Shift> Shifts
    {
        get
        {
            return _shifts;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_shifts == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _shifts = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ShiftPropertyName);
        }
}
```

When i run it i get this binding errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression  path error: 'SelectedShift' property 
not found on 'object' ''WeeklySchedule' (HashCode=7843366)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=SelectedShift; DataItem='WeeklySchedule' (HashCode=7843366);
 target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')
```

I really dont understand that much of the error, is it trying to find the property SelectedShift inside the WeeklySchedule class??

i tried to make it as clear as possible... 
Any ideas?, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your `DataTemplate` `DataContext` is of type `WorkScheduleViewModel`, and `SelectedShift` does not exist in `WorkScheduleViewModel`.
So you will have to set the `ListViews` `DataContext` to your `ViewModel`

Something like this should work

```
   <ListView  x:Name="ShiftListView" 
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ViewModel}}}"
              Grid.Column="0"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShiftlistViewTemplate}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Shifts}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShift, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```